# Computer Doesn't Always Turn on when Pressing Power Button

Tags: boot, motherboard, power-supply, power, post

I have a desktop and my case's power button stopped working after a while. I reverted to using a small screw driver or paper clip to turn my computer on by touching the contacts on the motherboard until the new switch I ordered arrived.

The new switch arrived and worked great for several days and now when I press the button the first time, the power switch lights up but that is it, nothing happens to the computer itself.

I have to turn power off on the computer, then try again. It typically works the second time, occasionally requires three times before turning on.

What could the problem and is there a way to solve it?

Notes:

- I replaced the power supply about a year ago as my old one went out.
- Once the computer is on, it works fine without any issue. In other words, it doesn't randomly cutoff.
- I never had an issue turning it on when I would do it with a paper clip or screw driver, the moment I touched the contacts it would turn on.
- I double checked the wires to ensure I had them connected securely and they are.

***UPDATE***

Jonathan Gray commented the following:

> If the LED lights up then it sounds like the computer is having an issue posting. Does it make a difference if you hold down the power button for a very quick or prolonged amount of time? It might very well be a power supply issue.

It does appear to make a difference the second time. The first time I push the button, regardless of length (quick or long), it doesn't turn on. The second time, If I push and hold the button down, it will almost always turn on.

If this is a posting issue as Jonathan suggest, what exactly does that mean and how do I fix the issue?

Comment: did you replace the wiring when you replaced teh switch? that a paperclip works, indicates the powerswitch header on the mobo is fine, and you just replaced the switch, so all that remains to replace is the wiring between the two.

Comment: If the LED lights up then it sounds like the computer is having an issue posting. Does it make a difference if you hold down the power button for a very quick or prolonged amount of time? It might very well be a power supply issue.

Comment: Could be a faulty PSU.

Comment: @FrankThomas - Yeah, the switch has brand new wiring that I am using.

Comment: @JonathanGray - Yes! I've noticed if I hold the power button down on the second try it will work most of the time. What is a posting issue and how do I solve it?

Comment: "Posting issue" means "an issue with POST" aka power on self test.  Nothing to do with online forums or wooden fence supports!